# Clicking on a field name whose unselectable is on using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to click on a field which is exactly not clickable. I am attaching the screenshot of the screen.

The Html code behind the page is:

```
<td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-TRAVNAME " style="width:  234px;" tabindex="0">
<div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-TRAVNAME"   unselectable="on">ARUNACHALAM/SHAN</div>
</td>
```

The code that I have written is in C# which is as follows:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ext - gen13']/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div")).Click();
```

Its throwing exception saying it is unable to find the field.

Can someone please help?[image]

Comment: Have you checked to ensure your xpath is valid/correct?

Comment: It is correct, because I have copied directly from the Inspect

Comment: OK, maybe instead of using `Thread.Sleep()` you could use a `WebDriverWait` to wait until the element is definitely visible.

Comment: I have tried that as well, the problem I think is not with the Thread.Sleep or WebDriverWait, it is with the field which has unselectable on, in that way it is unable to find the field name. I have got an answer in this link http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8371/selenium-element-not-selectable-for-a-kendo-ui-element     but I am not exactly sure as to how to use it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `WebDriverWait` as below :-

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
var el =    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("td.grid3-td-TRAVNAME div.x-grid3-col-TRAVNAME")));
el.Click();
```

**Edited** : If unfortunately it's not clickable due to `unselectable="on"`, remove this attribute property before clicking using `IJavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver.Instance, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
var el =    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.CssSelector("td.grid3-td-TRAVNAME div.x-grid3-col-TRAVNAME")));

IJavaScriptExecutor js = Driver.Instance as IJavaScriptExecutor;
el = (IWebElement)js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('unselectable'); return arguments[0];", el);
el.Click();
```

**Edited** :- cssSelector does not work here try using `By.Xpath()` as below :-

```
var el =    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Xpath(".//div[contains(text(), 'ARUNACHALAM/SHAN')]")));
```

Comment: Hi Saurabh, thanks for the answer, but I have already used it, the problem is the element is not clickable here, if you see the html code unselectable="on" here.

Comment: @Adrija then need to remove this attribute before click..:)

Comment: I tried with your edited code as well, it didn't work..threw me an exception saying timed out after 20secs, I also tried with Thread Sleep(1000), it gave me the exception saying unable to locate the element :(

Comment: @Adrija Once try with `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsExists` instead of `ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible` and let me know...:)

Comment: @Adrija and make sure this element is not inside any frame or iframe...:)

Comment: It says ExpectedConditions is having no defination for ElementIsExists, do we require separate class or namespace for it?

Comment: @Adrija sorry it's `ExpectedConditions.ElementExists`..just typo mistake..try this

Comment: Its still showing the same error Timed out after 20 secs :'(

Comment: I dont think so its in a separate frame, but its in a separate form.

Comment: @Adrija and what about frame?? Did you look for frame or iframe??

Comment: Ok once try using `By.Xpath(".//div[contains(text(), 'ARUNACHALAM/SHAN')]")` and let me know...:)

Answer (score 0):

### unSelectable attribute

The [unSelectable](http://help.dottoro.com/lhwdpnva.php) attribute sets whether the selection process can start in an element's content or not. If the unSelectable attribute of an element is set to `on`, then the element is selectable only if the selection starts outside the contents of the element.

The difference between the `unSelectable` attribute and the `-moz-user-select` and `-webkit-user-select` style properties is that the `-moz-user-select` and `-webkit-user-select` style properties specify whether an element can be selected while the `unSelectable` attribute only specifies whether the selection process can start in an element's content or not. Another difference is that the `unSelectable` attribute is not inherited while the `-moz-user-select` and `-webkit-user-select` style properties are inherited. It means that the `unSelectable` attribute must be set on all non-selectable elements regardless of whether the `unSelectable` attribute is set on the parent element of a non-selectable element or not.

---

### This usecase

The relevant HTML would have been helpful to construct a canonical answer. However if the element is a dynamic element or the website is [Kendo UI](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui) based, then to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *WebDriverWait* and *CssSelector*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("td.x-grid3-td-TRAVNAME > div.x-grid3-col-TRAVNAME"))).Click();
  ```
- Using *WebDriverWait* and *XPath*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//td[@class='x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-TRAVNAME ']/div[text()='ARUNACHALAM/SHAN']"))).Click();
  ```
- Using *IJavaScriptExecutor* and *CssSelector*:

  ```
  ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CssSelector, "td.x-grid3-td-TRAVNAME > div.x-grid3-col-TRAVNAME"))));
  ```
- Using IJavaScriptExecutor and `CssSelector`:

  ```
  ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-TRAVNAME ']/div[text()='ARUNACHALAM/SHAN']"))));
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevent detailed discussion in:

- [select kendo dropdown using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767150/select-kendo-dropdown-using-selenium-python/58767346#58767346)