# How to select kendo dropdown element with unselectable="on" attribute using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

*Unable to select the kendo dropdown using below code. The site can be reachable for checking the code.*

```
<span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default"><span unselectable="on" class="k-input">Chang</span><span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select"><span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span></span></span>



Code: 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get("https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/remotedatasource")
select = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="example"]/div/span/span/span[1]')[0]
select.SelectByValue("Chang");
print('Success')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the item with text as **Chang** within the kendo dropdown using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/remotedatasource")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.k-widget.k-dropdown[aria-owns='products_listbox']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.k-animation-container>div#products-list ul li[data-offset-index='1']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/remotedatasource")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='k-widget k-dropdown' and @aria-owns='products_listbox']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='k-animation-container']/div[@id='products-list']//ul//li[text()='Chang']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Browser Snapshot:
[image: Chang]

Comment: It's works, have any documentation for kendo controls check box, multi select, grid, etc using python selenium? Thanks in advance

Comment: @Vignesh I am not sure of any specific documentation but if you have raised a question I will like to have a look at it.

Comment: How can we select by dropdpwn list id? because xpath or css selector getting changed when we do changes in html and it requires to update xpath or css selector in test case code. What is an efficient way to handle this kind of situation?