# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException while clicking on span element with attribute "unselectable=on"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

What I am trying:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='TrailVersion, Testing_Demo']"));
```

Option 1:

```
element.click();
```

Option 2:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.click(element).build().perform();
action.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform(); 

  {Giving exception "org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite." }
```

Option 3:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

I would like to highlight that span tag contains attribute `<span unselectable = "on">`
I have tried all the above 3 options but unfortunately, nothing is working. I have tried different Xpath's for the same element too but in vain. The element has no unique ID or class.

Can anyone please help me resolve the issue?

Comment: 'unselectable' is pretty much clear. You have to get rid of the attribute (or change it's value to 'off') using javascript. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38751384/clicking-on-a-field-name-whose-unselectable-is-on-using-selenium

Answer (score 0):

### unSelectable attribute

The [unSelectable](http://help.dottoro.com/lhwdpnva.php) attribute sets whether the selection process can start in an element's content or not. If the unSelectable attribute of an element is set to `on`, then the element is selectable only if the selection starts outside the contents of the element.

> In Firefox, Google Chrome and Safari, the [-moz-user-select](http://help.dottoro.com/lcrlukea.php) and [-webkit-user-select](http://help.dottoro.com/lcrlukea.php#-webkit-user-select) style properties are used for implementing similar functionality.

The difference between the `unSelectable` attribute and the `-moz-user-select` and `-webkit-user-select` style properties is that the `-moz-user-select` and `-webkit-user-select` style properties specify whether an element can be selected while the `unSelectable` attribute only specifies whether the selection process can start in an element's content or not. Another difference is that the `unSelectable` attribute is not inherited while the `-moz-user-select` and `-webkit-user-select` style properties are inherited. It means that the `unSelectable` attribute must be set on all non-selectable elements regardless of whether the `unSelectable` attribute is set on the parent element of a non-selectable element or not.

---

### This usecase

The relevant HTML would have been helpful to construct a canonical answer. However if the element is a dynamic element or the website is [Kendo UI](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui) based, then to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610553/selenium-check-for-the-presence-of-element/50621712#50621712) and `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[starts-with(., 'TrailVersion') and contains(., 'Testing_Demo')]"))).click();
  ```
- Using *Actions* and `xpath`:

  ```
  new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[starts-with(., 'TrailVersion') and contains(., 'Testing_Demo')]")))).click().build().perform();
  ```
- Using [JavascriptExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52689880/what-is-javascriptexecutor-in-selenium/52698089#52698089) and `xpath`:

  ```
  ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[starts-with(., 'TrailVersion') and contains(., 'Testing_Demo')]"))));
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevent detailed discussion in:

- [select kendo dropdown using selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767150/select-kendo-dropdown-using-selenium-python/58767346#58767346)